# Android SimpleCursorAdapter Update when database updates

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have an application that uses SyncService and SyncAdapter. Within the application, I have an activity using a SimpleCursorAdapter. How do I go about updating the list when the database updates?

I have read that I should use `adapter.changeCursor()` or `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but where do I call it? And how would I know when the database is updated?

Also, I have heard that I could use a ContentProvider instead of a direct database access and the list would update automatically, is that true?

**EDIT:**
I update the database in the method onPerformSync() in my SyncAdapter class

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged() in your insert data function, after insert query.

Comment: How would I call it from another class?

Comment: From activity when you call a function from inserting data in database class at that you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() from that activity.

Comment: I don't insert my data in the database in the same activity where I display the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use notifyDataSetChanged() like:

```
mListView.setAdapter(someAdapter);
someAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: But I don't insert the data in a activity, I insert data in a SyncAdapter in the onPerformSync()